# Magento: Get customer detail fields before redirecting to payment gateway

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I'm currently in the process of attempting to create a Authroize.net SIM payment method which redirects the customer to a secured site to fill out CC info. I'm needing to collect information from the checkout process such as the customer billing and shipping address, total, tax, shipping (and shipping method), and grand total. Were do I obtain these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set up your payment method extension and you are in payment method context then you can access this information through

```
$info = $this->getInfoInstance();
$info->getOrder();
$info->getQuote();
$info->getOrder()->getBillingAddress();
```

and so on. Just be sure that you follow the flow described in  Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract and that your methods class extends this class.